# input fields not showing default value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with some input fields. I have value="something here" set on most of them. However, when i load the page in firefox the input fields are not filled in.

Firebug shows a value attribute with the correct value in it. But its not showing on the screen. When I submit the form, it doesnt pass the values either.

Here's the output from my PHP Script which just dumps the array.

```
}
[servDate] => 07-07-2011
[time1] => 8:00
[odo1] => 12345
[report1] => 
[time2] => 8:30
[odo2] => 12350
[report2] => 
[time4] => 9:00
[odo4] => 12359
[report4] => SUBJECT DEPARTS HOME
[time5] => 9:30
[odo5] => 12369
[report5] => SUBJECT ARRIVES AT WORK
[time98] => 9:35
[odo98] => 12369
[report98] => 
[time99] => 10:00
[odo99] => 12399
[report99] => 
[servHrs] => 
[id] => 
)
```

The form is as follows:

```
<form id="reportForm">
    Service Date: <input type="text" name="servDate" id="servDate" size="10" value="<? echo date("m-d-Y"); ?>" /><button id="servDateBtn"><img src="../includes/calendar.png" /></button><br />
    <table id="reportTable" name="reportTable">
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Odometer</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <TD width="20px">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="time1" id="time1" size="4" /> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#time1').timepicker({
                        showPeriod: false,
                        showLeadingZero: false
                    });
                });
            </script>
            </TD>
            <td><input type="text" name="odo1" id="odo1" class="odo" size="6" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="report1" id="report1" size="42" value="Dispatched Investigator." readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </TR>
        <tr>
            <TD width="20px">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="time2" id="time2" size="4" /> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#time2').timepicker({
                        showPeriod: false,
                        showLeadingZero: false
                    });
                });
            </script>
            </TD>
            <td><input type="text" name="odo2" id="odo2" class="odo" size="6" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="report2" id="report2" size="42" value="Investigator arrived at first field location." readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </TR>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <TD width="20px">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="time98" id="time98" size="4" /> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#time98').timepicker({
                        showPeriod: false,
                        showLeadingZero: false
                    });
                });
            </script>
            </TD>
            <td><input type="text" name="odo98" id="odo98" class="odo" size="6" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="report98" id="report98" size="42" value="Investigator departed last field location." readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </TR>
        <tr>
            <TD width="20px">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="time99" id="time99" size="4" /> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#time99').timepicker({
                        showPeriod: false,
                        showLeadingZero: false
                    });
                });
            </script>
            </TD>
            <td><input type="text" name="odo99" id="odo99" class="odo" size="6" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="report99" id="report99" size="42" value="Investigator suspended." readonly="readonly" /></td>
        </TR>
    </table>
    <br /><button id="addEntry">Add Entry</button>&nbsp;<button id="delEntry">Delete Entry</button>
    <br />
    Service Hours: <input type="text" name="servHrs" id="servHrs" size="4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" class="client" value="<? echo $id ?>" />
</form>
```

which opens in a jquery dialog.

The other forms on my page open in a dialog box and work fine. I've verified I'm not using ANY duplicate IDs or NAME tags. Whats weirder is sometimes it will work and sometimes it wont.

For security reasons, I'm not allowed to show u the actual page as this system contains confidential client information.

Comment: I don't know about the problem with the values... but maybe putting all the JavaScript in one separate document or just in your `<head>` and not using tables would make the code simpler to debug and more standard.

Comment: There's no reason the fields shouldn't be present on submission. Do you have any JS massaging the form onsubmit that's not shown here?

Answer (score 2):

Does it only happen when the page is reloaded? If so, it's likely because Firefox is remembering the old values. Does it happen if you open the page in a new tab?

Comment: If i open in a new window or new tab the values show up. So how can i fix that? After the form is submitted the page reloads but the default values are gone. Unless I open in a new tab or window.

Comment: If i add <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"> to my page it still doesnt work. Seems only way is to open a new browser window or force everything to reload with a random uid in the address

Comment: Ok here's what I did to fix it. Firefox always has to cache a page. But you can force it to recache every time the page loads by using the cache-control NO STORE. So here is the meta tag i used at the top of my page:

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE, NO-STORE">

Hope someone else finds this useful.

Comment: OK i take that back. Its still erasing the fields in firefox. Sometimes all of them are gone and sometimes just a few are gone. Only way to correct this is to open a new window. Any other ideas? I cant have that.

Comment: That… Is very strange. Does it still happen if you temporarily disable JavaScript?

Comment: yes it still happens. I'm not using any funky code. Its just a form with value="sometext". The form gets hidden and unhidden with javascript. But with JS off...it shows up first time (like always) but if you refresh....its gone. This is in firefox. I havent tried with IE or Chrome

Comment: It does it in Chrome too. But not in IE.

Comment: That's very strange then… Can you post an anonymized version of it somewhere online so I can recreate it?

Comment: Facing same problem by me too.. It's very strange.. Did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So I know its been ages since this question was asked. But because there is no valid answer here and to help people in the future:

Browser does store `defaultValue` as been already mentioned. But using a meta tag that directs browser to not cache at all is a very bad solution.

**Cause:**

The problem this matter even becomes an issue was (in my case) application was assigning an empty `defaultValue` and when the data from the server was coming in it wasn't updating it.

**Solution:**

Avoid re-assignment of `defaultValue` from **Empty** to **Actual Value**. Just render the input field when the **Actual Value is available**.